# Any reason why a loop wouldn't terminate even with an 'i' limiting value of repeats?

Tags: c, loops

I'm doing this assignment for college in C, should be fairly simple, but a loop in it doesn't seem to terminate so the code won't work properly; even if I put in an i value to limit the amount of times it loops. Tried it with a for loop too, still gets stuck.

The code is supposed to take in values of coefficients and try to work out a root for a cubic equation by finding the midpoint between two large values and trying that out to see if it gets 0, if it doesn't, it should change one of the limits to the midpoint value. Here's the relevant code:

```
int main (void)

{

    int  i, u=1000, l=-1000;
    float a, b, c, d, mid, y;

    scanf(" %f %f %f %f", &a, &b, &c, &d);

    while (abs(u - l) > 0.001 && i < 10)
    {
        mid= (u + l)/2;
        y = a * pow(mid, 3) + b* pow(mid, 2) + c * mid + d;

        if(y == 0) break;
        else if(y < 0) l = mid;
        else u = mid;

        i++;
    }
    printf("\nThere is a root at: x = %.3f\n", mid);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

edit: Oh my god I'm an idiot. Always the small things. The code still isn't working but at least it's not stuck anymore, thanks guys!

Comment: What is the value of `i` initialised to? Because if it's equal to -100000 or something, it's gonna take a long time to reach 10.

Comment: Debuggers help you find these things. Or just `printf("%i\n", i);` in there, and it will show you what's going wrong.

Comment: If the answers helped you, we would appreciate it if you would select an answer to accept.  See [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things. Initialize i to 0. this will ensure it terminates after 10 loops.
More important for your problem though, you have declared u and l as integers, I think you need to declare them as floats.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `i`, but did not initialize it, so it is set to whatever random value was left in memory.

For this example, lets say that value was `-12,345`.

Then `i` can be incremented over 12,000 times before it is greater than 10!
Your loop will run when i is incremented 12,355 times, and its value becomes 10, and the test `i < 10` finally fails.

To fix this, initialize `i = 0`:

```
int i=0;
```

Comment: Undefined Behavior means anything at all can happen, including having your disk formatted, or having demons appear from your serial port.  I do *not* think this is an Undefined Behavior situation.  Rather, I believe it is well-defined that you will get *some* valid integer from `i`; you just cannot predict which value it will be.
No risk of Demons.

Comment: In that case you are thinking wrong: `i` is a memory-less `auto` variable (could be declared `register`), thus reading it before its initialized is straight UB.

Comment: `i` is not declared `register`. As a regular, automatic variable, I believe both reading from it and writing to it (rvalue & lvalue) are well defined and safe, even if its initial value is not known

Comment: You are mis-reading: I wrote is memory-less auto-storage-class variable, so it could have been declared register without changing anything else.

Comment: The undefined behavior is in the variable initialization, not the read. Reading an integer, register or otherwise, is always defined behavior. Whatever value the integer was initialized with (or last written with) will be read, regardless of the backing. The compiler may optimize away the memory backing of the integer, but it can't optimize away the read behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `i`:  `int i = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you! You need to initialize `i`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
    int  i = 0, u = 1000, l =- 1000;
    float a, b, c, d, mid, y;

    scanf(" %f %f %f %f", &a, &b, &c, &d);

    while (abs(u-l)>0.001 && i<10)
    {
        mid = (u + l)/2;
        y = a*pow(mid,3) + b* pow(mid,2) + c*mid + d;

        if(y == 0)
            break;
        else if(y<0)
            l = mid;
        else
            u = mid;

        i++;
    }

    printf("\nThere is a root at: x = %.3f\n", mid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make `u` and `l` be floats then your while-loop terminates without `i`.  Before that, `abs(u-l)` where `u-l` are `int`s will only terminate if a root is at zero.  You also need to use fabs() instead of abs():

```
int main (void)
{
  float u=1000.0, l=-1000.0;
  float a, b, c, d, mid, y;

  scanf(" %f %f %f %f", &a, &b, &c, &d);

  while (fabs(u - l) > 0.001)
  {
    mid= (u + l)/2.0;
    y = a * pow(mid, 3) + b* pow(mid, 2) + c * mid + d;
    if(y == 0) break;
    else if(y < 0) l = mid;
    else u = mid;
  }
  printf("\nThere is a root at: x = %.3f\n", mid);
}
```

Seems like you still have something wrong in the bisection algorithm condition when you reset l and u to mid.  I'm attaching a fixed version, and I used different variable names (sorry) to keep my head clear:

```
#define NMAX 1000
#define TOL  0.00001
int sign( float x ) {
   if (x > 0.0) return 1;
   if (x < 0.0) return -1;
   return 0;
}
int main (void)
{
    int n=0;
    float fa, fc, b=1000.0, a=-1000.0;
    float p3,p2,p1,p0,c;

    scanf(" %f %f %f %f", &p3, &p2, &p1, &p0);

    while(n<NMAX)
    {
        c = (a + b)/2.0;
        fc = p3*pow(c, 3) + p2*pow(c, 2) + p1*c + p0;

        if(fc == 0.0 || (b-a)/2.0 < TOL ) break;

        fa = p3*pow(a, 3) + p2*pow(a, 2) + p1*a + p0;
        if( sign(fc) == sign(fa) )
          a = c;
        else
          b = c;
        n++;
    }
    if(n==NMAX) {
       printf("Method failed.\n");
    } 
    else {
       printf("\nThere is a root at: x = %.3f\n", c);
    }
}
```